# creating a custom maps and visualizing data

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, datamaps

I wrote a simulation of a PDS ( Public Distribution System). I considered only one state of India. As in the simulation inventories are moving from a district to another.

I want to make a data visualization as a part of UI where I will be able to see the movements.

Is there any libraries available for data visualization where I can make a custom map of any Indian state and arcs between the districts representing inventory movement.

Thank you.